# Delete only files using S3 DeleteObject keeping directory structure intact. How to do?

Tags: java, spring, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-s3

I want to delete only a specific file from the S3 bucket and want to keep the directory structure as it is.

Trying to use this but it's deleting the entire folded.

amazonS3.deleteObject(bucketName, filess.getKey());

bucketName : test-bucket
key: devb/CAHSE/ATT/2020081103083985847118.pdf

I want to delete only 2020081103083985847118.pdf from the directory.

Comment: It's not deleting the folder. There is no folder. If you want the *appearance* of a folder after deleting that object then create a zero-sized object named `devb/CAHSE/ATT/` that represents the folder.

Answer (score 4):

S3 doesn't really have directories. See the documentation on this [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/using-folders.html)

> In Amazon S3, buckets and objects are the primary resources, and objects are stored in buckets. Amazon S3 has a flat structure instead of a hierarchy like you would see in a file system. However, for the sake of organizational simplicity, the Amazon S3 console supports the folder concept as a means of grouping objects. It does this by using a shared name prefix for objects (that is, objects have names that begin with a common string). Object names are also referred to as key names.

So if you have no objects that begin with your preferred prefix, there won't be a "directory" either.

To expand, key `a/b/c` isn't a file `c` in directory `a/b/`, it is an object in your bucket with the key `a/b/c`. You could call it `a|b|c` or `a6b6c` if you wanted, and it would work just the same.